# Add questions from Excel to jQuery quiz

Tags: jquery, excel

I made a quiz the simplest way possible using jQuery. There are questions with 4 possible answers, you select the answer and check it. If the answer is right it tells you and if it is wrong it tells you and you go to the next question. Fine.

I have a lot of questions in an Excel document, in one column I have the questions, in three more columns I have possible answers and in the fourth column I have the right answer.

**What is the easiest way to import the questions and answers to my quiz?**

I could put them manually, but there are a lot of questions, more than 600 and I'm sure there must be a way to do it faster. The quiz works fine.

This is the code for the quiz:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){ 
$(".correct").hide();
$(".ohhh").hide();
$(".final").hide();
$(".question").hide();
$(".warning").hide();
$(".current").show(); // the first question

$("#comprobar").click(function(){ // when checking the answer, if it right   
                                     tell the user that's right
    if ($( "input:checked" ).val() == "true") {
        $(".warning").hide();
        $(".ohhh").hide();
        $(".correct").show();
        $('#check').attr("disabled", true); // a button
        if ( $option.hasClass('.big') ) {
            $option.addClass('.big'); 
        }
        else if ($( "input:checked" ).val() == "false"){
            $(".warning").hide();
            $(".correct").hide();
            $(".ohhh").show();
            $('this').find('.correct').addclass('big'); // if it is wrong, 
                                                           tell the user
        } else {
            $(".warning").show(); // if no answer is checked, tell the user
        }
            $( "input:checked" ).val() == reset;  // clear the checked value
    }); 

    $("#continue").click(function(){
    $('#check').attr("disabled", false);
        $(".correct").hide();
        $(".ohhh").hide();
        $(".warning").hide();
        $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
            .next().show().addClass('current');        
                if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
                $('#continue').hide();
                $('#check').hide();
                $(".final").show();
            } 
            $('.actual').trigger("reset");
        });     
    });
```

Comment: use a serverside language like asp.net or php, etc. to parse the excel and render the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSON.

Excel can be exported as a CSV file.

You can convert a CSV file to JSON using various online tools, such as: https://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/

With that tool, you dont even need to export or anything, just copy and paste.

Then you can parse the JSON using jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/